# splitting string of unicode characters in R

Tags: r

I have a column of unicode characters that I need to split so I can calulate the frequency of them. I have tried a number of different ways to try and split these but am not making any headway.  The input format of the data is

```
[1] "\U00010603"                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2] "\U0001076b\U00010631\U0001076b"                                                                                                                                                                
[3] "\U00010631\U00010633"
[4] "\U0001061a\U00010655\U00010609\U00010631"
...
```

and id like the output to be

```
[1] "\U00010603"                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2] "\U0001076b"
[3] "\U00010631"
[4] "\U0001076b" 
...
```

I have tried

```
df <- c("\U00010603","\U0001076b\U00010631\U0001076b", "\U00010631\U00010633","\U0001061a\U00010655\U00010609\U00010631")

df1 <- strsplit(df, "\\", fixed = TRUE)

df1 <- lapply(df,strsplit, split = '\\', fixed = TRUE)
```

I have also tried various forms of `\U0`.  Thank you for your help.
The output is basically an identical list of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are UNICODE CHARACTERS. You could tell that from the name. Hence to split them use:

```
strsplit(df,"")
[[1]]
[1] "\U00010603"

[[2]]
[1] "\U0001076b" "\U00010631"          "\U0001076b"

[[3]]
[1] "\U00010631" "\U00010633"

[[4]]
[1] "\U0001061a" "\U00010655"          "\U00010609" "\U00010631"
```

Note that the first element has only 1 character etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have realized that.  Thank you for helping me understand.